# If condition to notify the app only if a new data was added to the database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-notifications

We are firebase and AS beginners. We are developing an android app that notifies the user whenever a new data is added to the database. But what we have so far, is an app that notifies the user whenever the app is opened even with no new data added.

```
public class AssignmentListArt extends AppCompatActivity {


ArrayList<assignmentArt> listArt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_assignment_list_art);

    recyclerViewArt = findViewById(R.id.assignmentListArt);

    databaseArt = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("yearlevel").child("1").child("ART").child("Assignments");

    recyclerViewArt.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerViewArt.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    listArt = new ArrayList<>();
    myAdapterArt = new MyAdapterArt(this, listArt);
    recyclerViewArt.setAdapter(myAdapterArt);

    databaseArt.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            // fetch all data data in assignmentArt field
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
                assignmentArt assignmentArt = dataSnapshot.getValue(com.example.timemanagementapp.assignmentArt.class);
                listArt.add(assignmentArt);

            }
            myAdapterArt.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        }
    });

    databaseArt.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

            if (new ArrayList<assignmentArt>().equals(new ArrayList<assignmentArt>())){
                Toast.makeText(AssignmentListArt.this, "An error in the database occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                notification();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}

private void notification() {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
        NotificationChannel channel =
                new NotificationChannel("n", "n", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

        NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "n")
                .setContentText("New Assignment!")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_notifications)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentText("New Assignment in ART has been added.");

        NotificationManagerCompat managerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        managerCompat.notify(999, builder.build());
    }
}
```

}

How do you get the count of the array. And how will you code it so that the current array count vs the array count when a new data is added will be the condition for notification. Thank you

Comment: `How do you code it so that the current array count vs the array count when a new data is added will be the condition for notification. ` how do you get the count of items in your current array ? how do you get an array of items from firebase ? how do you get the count of that array ?

Comment: Lots of confusion in your question.pls make it clear what you want and how the data driven in array list

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information  a_local_nobody asked for, and please also respond with @.